# How to enable CORS in geoserver 2.9?

Tags: apache, cors, wampserver, geoserver

I am working on a web mapping app, that needs access to Geoserver, I installed wampserver to load my php and html/js files.

I can access data from Geoserver using jsonp format but I cannot send WFS-T requests for add/update/delete operations due to the CORS policy.

I tried to implement many solutions found on the web and here in stackoverflow but I get the same problem

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 3 ms]

Blocage d’une requête multi-origines (Cross-Origin Request) : la politique « Same Origin » ne permet pas de consulter la ressource distante située sur http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs. Raison : l’en-tête CORS « Access-Control-Allow-Origin » est manquant.

which means that the request is blocked due to the absence of Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

[image: I checked the headers_module in apache]

After checking the headers_module in apache and adding the following lines to the httpd.conf file in C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\conf

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
</IfModule>
```

This is from the Apache side, Concerning the Geoserver Side how can I enable it ?

Comment: The receiving site has to set a CORS policy. There is no point in the Calling app being allowed to amend a security poilicy on the receiving server???!!!???

Comment: you're right I'll edit the question

Answer (score 2):

Open the `web.xml` file in your `WEB-INF\lib` directory and search for CORS. Uncomment the 2 CORS filter sections and restart geoserver.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it has been a while since I switched from using geoserver, I'm upvoting this answer in case someone could test it to confirm :)

Comment: No dramas mate. What are you using now? If you don't mind me asking. I'm using Mapserver in production but just started playing around with vector tiles and I'm trialling a few different products

Comment: I realized that I don't even need a wfs service for this use case, I'm sending data asynchronously in JSON format from my python/Django backend